# voice assitant with tkinter for creating gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frontend

How to give interface to the voice assistant. When you start the program it opens one window there it run the voice assistant program .it shows image when voice recognising. whie taking commands and the results are shuold shown in different colors in boxes.when you close the window the program will should also stop .

the whole program i done in python.so i tried using tkinter.when i create window as function and call it in main function the window only show but the voice assistant program not start working.

this the sample code i tried. when  i run it the window opened but the voice recogniton not work. once i colose it manualy then the voice recognition start. how can i embbed the the gui program to voice assitant.

```
import tkinter as tk
import wikipedia
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import time
from tkinter import *
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tkth
import pyjokes

def winn():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.title('voice assistant')
    root.geometry('500x600')
    #root.configure(bg='red')
    root['background']='skyblue'
    root.mainloop()


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir !")
    elif hour>= 12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon Sir !")
    else:
        speak("Good Evening Sir !")
    assname = ("Voice Assisant")
    speak("I am your Assistant")
    speak(assname)


def username():
    speak("What should i call you sir")
    uname = takeCommand()
    speak("Welcome Mister")
    speak(uname)
    columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
    print("Welcome Mr.", uname)
    speak("How can i Help you, Sir")


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Unable to Recognize your voice.")
        return "None"
    return query


`if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()
    winn()
    wishMe()
    username()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")          
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 3)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)
        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")
        elif 'how are you' in query:
            speak("I am fine, Thank you")
            speak("how are you, Sir")
        elif 'fine' in query:
            speak("It's good to know that your fine")
        elif "what's your name" in query or "What is your name" in query:
            speak("My Boss call me Mayuri")
            speak("But my friends call me Mayu")
        elif "do you have friends" in query:
            speak("Yes I have many friends")
        elif "who is your best friend" in query:
            speak("I have many friends but for me , Amenda is my best friend")
        elif 'exit' in query:
            speak("Thanks for giving me your time")
            exit()
        elif "who made you" in query or "who created you" in query:
            speak("I have been created by Gokul Raj")
        elif "I love you" in query:
            speak("ooo no but I have already have a boyfriend")
        elif 'joke' in query:
            speak(pyjokes.get_joke())
        elif "will you be my girlfriend" in query:
            speak("I'm not sure about, may be you should give me some time")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `winn()` the execution stops there because root.mainloop is an infinite loop. See below example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def winn():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.title('voice assistant')
    root.geometry('500x600')
    root['background']='skyblue'
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    winn()
    print("Not printed until root.mainloop exists!")
```

I recommend you create the GUI within a class: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-object-oriented-window/

where `winn` function is going to be the `__init__` method; and the other functions will be methods within this class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).